# What does the TW mean in NANYA RAM?

Tags: memory, dell-poweredge

I brought a used R710 which came with 32GB of ECC Nanya RAM, all of the RAM sticks are identical (NT4GC72B4NA1NL-CG) 4GB RAM sticks, however, they have a number next to them that is different, e.g:
0934.TW
1010.TW
e.t.c.

Also, there appears to be another model number towards the bottom of the label which is different despite the RAM model numbers being the same

Finally, there is also a number printed onto the RAM itself:
NIN0933 and NIN1006

What do these numbers mean?

Comment: The first is obviously the date code. But the rest are totally irrelevant.

Comment: So the TW code means nothing?

Comment: Probably a region code (i.e. Taiwan)

Comment: Seems reasonable, but again it doesn't matter. None of those codes are relevant to operating the server.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the information.

Comment: @bluebot, in case it has been solved, add please an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the other codes do not mean anything and the RAM sticks are identical (since their storage and speed is as well)